how to find year_month_date from a string in snowflake
I am using snowflake to get some data. I have one requirement that i want to extract year_month_day from a string.
a string would be 'IN_2001_02_23_guid' and I want to extract 20010223 from this string.
Could you please help me to find this?
Thank you.

You could also try  substr and get the date,   select to_date(substr('IN_2001_02_23_guid' ,4,10) , 'YYYY_MM_DD') from dual;

@Dave's answer is probably the best for your use case if the pattern is well defined.Otherwise  REGEXP_SUBSTR can be  used for cases when it is needed to  extract a substring that matches a regular expression pattern.
Please note : This function doesn't modify the string; it simply returns the part of the string that matches the pattern.
Solution using REGEXP_SUBSTR :
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('IN_2001_02_23_guid', '\\d+', 1, 1) || 
REGEXP_SUBSTR('IN_2001_02_23_guid', '\\d+', 1, 2) || 
REGEXP_SUBSTR('IN_2001_02_23_guid', '\\d+', 1, 3) AS extracted_date;

Explanation :
\\d+ represents digits 
REGEXP_SUBSTR('IN_2001_02_23_guid', '\\d+', 1, 1)  -- 1,1 means start from position 1 and pick up the first match i.e 2001
REGEXP_SUBSTR('IN_2001_02_23_guid', '\\d+', 1, 2)  -- 1,2 means start from position 1 and pick up the second match i.e 02
REGEXP_SUBSTR('IN_2001_02_23_guid', '\\d+', 1, 3)  -- 1,3 means start from position 1 and pick up the third match i.e 23


If your format will always be similar to the example, the easy way is to replace all characters that are not digits with '' using REGEXP_REPLACE.
select regexp_replace(val,'[^0-9]','') as y_m_d from tbl;




Y_M_D




20010223



